# How to base64-decode large files in PHP

Tags: php, memory, base64

My PHP web application has an API that can recieve reasonably large files (up to 32 MB) which are base64 encoded. The goal is to write these files somewhere on my filesystem. Decoded of course. What would be the least resource intensive way of doing this?

**Edit:** Recieving the files through an API means that I have a 32MB string in my PHP app, not a 32 MB source file somewhere on disk. I need to get that string decoded an onto the filesystem.

Using PHP's own base64_decode() isn't cutting it because it uses a *lot* of memory so I keep running into PHP's memory limit (I know, I could raise that limit but I don't feel good about allowing PHP to use 256MB or so per process).

Any other options? Could I do it manually? Or write the file to disk encoded and call some external command? Any thought?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Even though this has an accepted answer, I have a different suggestion.

If you are pulling the data from an API, you should not store the entire payload in a variable. Using curl or other HTTP fetchers you can automatically store your data in a file.

Assuming you are fetching the data through a simple GET url:

```
$url = 'http://www.example.com/myfile.base64';
$target = 'localfile.data';

$rhandle = fopen($url,'r');
stream_filter_append($rhandle, 'convert.base64-decode');

$whandle = fopen($target,'w');

stream_copy_to_stream($rhandle,$whandle);
fclose($rhandle);
fclose($whandle);
```

Benefits:

- Should be faster (less copying of huge variables)
- Very little memory overhead

If you must grab the data from a temporary variable, I can suggest this approach:

```
$data = 'your base64 data';
$target = 'localfile.data';

$whandle = fopen($target,'w');
stream_filter_append($whandle, 'convert.base64-decode',STREAM_FILTER_WRITE);

fwrite($whandle,$data);

fclose($whandle);
```

Comment: A nice idea, but not what I am looking for. In my case, client applications are pushing big files over XML-RPC (HTTP POST) to my server (along with a couple of other parameters). Clients can be behind NAT and firewalls, so fetching the data from the client using GET is not possible.

Comment: If the structure of the xml rpc response is somewhat static, you could manually traverse through the response body, so you can still completely avoid all the memory usage.

If you must put the data in a temporary variable, you can change the setup a bit. (I'm updating the example right after the example ;))

Comment: Thanks for the update. I find it superior to the answer I originally accepted.

Comment: In regards to your second example would this differ any if you had to accept a file upload via POST and push it from your server to a soap server?

Comment: file_put_contents() expects the first parameter to be a string, in this case a resource is passed. I'm getting such an error in the above code

Comment: Sorry, that lasst file_put_contents should have just been fwrite()

Answer (score 11):

Decode the data in smaller chunks. Four characters of Base64 data equal three bytes of “Base256” data.

So you could group each 1024 characters and decode them to 768 octets of binary data:

```
$chunkSize = 1024;
$src = fopen('base64.data', 'rb');
$dst = fopen('binary.data', 'wb');
while (!feof($src)) {
    fwrite($dst, base64_decode(fread($src, $chunkSize)));
}
fclose($dst);
fclose($src);
```

Comment: Thanks. One thing before I mark this as accepted: In my original question I mention that the source file comes through an API. So, it's a variable (a 32 MB string) in PHP and not a file you read from. Is there something I can use instead of your fread() that returns me chunks of a string efficiently? I.e. without making too many duplicate copies that gobble up memory?

Comment: You can read from the input via `php://input`. See http://docs.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good idea transfer 32Mb string. But I have a solution for my task, that can accept any size files from browser to app server. Algorithm:
**Client**

1. Javascript: Read file from INPUT with FileReader and readAsDataURL() to FILE var.
2. Cut all of data in FILE from start to first "," position Split it with array_chunks by max_upload_size/max_post_size php var.
3. Send chunk with UID, chunk number and chunks quantity and wait for response, then send another chunk one by one.

**Server Side**
Write each chunk until the last one. Then do base64 with streams:

```
$src = fopen($source, 'r');
$trg = fopen($target, 'w');
stream_filter_append($src, 'convert.base64-decode');
stream_copy_to_stream($src, $trg);
fclose($src);
fclose($trg);
```

... now you have your base64 decoded file in $target local path. Note! You can not read and write the same file, so $source and $target must be different.