# string base64 to integer/float/char array in php

Tags: php, base64

I would like to convert a base64 string to other types, ie integer, float, and char array.

In Java I can use a [ByteBuffer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) object, so it's easy to get values with methods like `stream.getInt()`, `stream.getLong()`, `stream.getChar()`, `stream.getFloat()`, etc.

But how to do this in PHP?

Edit: I tried the [base64-decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php) PHP function, but this one decode a string, I want to decode numbers.

Edit2:

In Java:

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ByteBuffer stream = ByteBuffer.wrap(DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary("AAGdQw=="));
        while (stream.hasRemaining()) {
            System.out.println(stream.getInt());
        }
    }
}
```

displays `105795`

But in php:

```
$nb = base64_decode('AAGdQw=='); // the result is not a stringified number, neither printable
settype($nb, 'int');
echo $nb;
```

displays `0`, because `base64_decode('AAGdQw==')` is not printable.

Comment: have you tried anything so far? perhaps reading the manual, especially about [base64_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php) and [type juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php)?

Comment: Of course I tried base64_decode, but I don't want to decode a string, I want also to decode integers and floats.

Comment: that's why i linked to the page about type juggling.

Comment: And I don't want to cast "64" to 64. Please see my edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to use `unpack` to convert the decoded string into a byte array, from which you then can reconstruct the integer:

```
<?php
$s = 'AAGdQw==';
$dec = base64_decode($s);
$ar = unpack("C*", $dec);
$i= ($ar[1]<<24) + ($ar[2]<<16) + ($ar[3]<<8) + $ar[4];

var_dump($i);
//output int(105795)
```

floats could be re-assembled with the `pack`-function, which creates a variable from a byte array.

but be advised that you have to take a lot of care about both data types AND the underlying hardware; especially the endianness (byte order) of the processor and the word size of the processor (32bit int differs from 64bit int) - therefore, if possible, you should use a text-based protocol, like JSON - which you can base64-encode, too.

- [unpack](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unpack.php)
- [pack](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php)
- [sandbox example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7165859b71cf67a0e9cddcbc14be7e42f86a3091)

Answer (score 0):

Decode a content as is and cast a result to any type through [type casting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting) or some [varialbe handling function](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.var.php) such as [`settype()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.settype.php).

If encoded file is large and you worried about memory consumption, you can use [stream filters](https://www.php.net/manual/kr/filters.convert.php) ([relevant answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/888461/how-to-base64-decode-large-files-in-php)).

Comment: Thank you. I tried but I don't understand why `settype(base64_decode('AAGdQw=='), 'int')` returns `1`.

Comment: `settype()` accepts argument by reference (see the manual), so you need to assign decoding result to a variable and apply `settype`. Also you can use [`intval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php).

Comment: Works better. The fact is my base64 string do not contains a stringified integer, it contains the integer itself: ie `AAGdQw==` is supposed to be `105795`, but the decoded string is not printable, so I don't think I can use it with `intval()`. See my edit.