# My PHP script keep throwing "Out of memory"

Tags: php

I have a php script that keeps throwing an error on the following line

```
base64_encode(serialize(array($data, $context)))
```

Here is the error

> Out of memory (allocated 471859200) (tried to allocate 234607507
>   bytes)

I have added the following two line before calling the `base64_encode()` method

```
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
```

As you can see, I am giving the script all the available physical memory (16GB)

What could be causing this error?

Comment: Are you using 32-bit PHP? There's a limit on how much memory the interpreter is physically possible to use.

Comment: Your code is probably causing the issue, but I can't see any.

Comment: It seems that `$data` and/or `$context` are very large

Comment: @HerrSerker yes they are. but why would my script runs out of memory?

Comment: Try checking phpinfo() if your memory limit is being applied

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I think I am using 32 bit. I checked the phpinfo() output (PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE  x86 )

Comment: The error message says that you have 450MB allocated and trying to allocate more 223MB (not ever close to 32-bit memory limit). So or your memory limit isn't `-1` or your physical memory is over.

Comment: I just added `ini_set('memory_limit', '2000M');` but that gave me the following error `Out of memory (allocated 473956352) (tried to allocate 234607507 bytes)`

Comment: Set memory limit to 128M ( or another reasonable number) and ensure that your available RAM is at least that amount. Then when you get a message that PHP exceeded memory limit redesign your code in such a way that you do not hit the limit anymore. Giving PHP all your RAM is a very bad idea.

Comment: @MikeA please tell me whats the memory limit on phpinfo()!

Comment: Just how gigantic is this data you're trying to serialize?

Answer (score 0):

PHP produces two memory-related error messages:

- When [memory_limit](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit) is exceeded, e.g.:

  > Allowed memory size of %zu bytes exhausted (tried to allocate %zu bytes)
- When PHP is unable to get more memory from the OS:

  > Out of memory (allocated %zu) (tried to allocate %zu bytes)

… with minor wording variations depending on the exact context (see PHP source code at [Zend\zend_alloc.c](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/d6e32c6ba7cd6b608e32c5ddb078e688b7031547/Zend/zend_alloc.c#L979) for details).

Using a simile, you can exhaust your disk quota or the disk can fill up.

The second situation is basically a crash and is relatively easy to find if you run memory-intensive tasks in a 32-bit PHP process. There's no fixed rule but when your needs get close to 1GB bad things happen. If you [determine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5423848/checking-if-your-code-is-running-on-64-bit-php) that you're running 32-bit PHP (the OS architecture doesn't matter), and even if you don't, you may want to consider a rewrite.

I have no idea about your use case so these are only vague tips:

- I presume you `base64_encode()` your data to submit it elsewhere. Perhaps you don't need to hold the entire data in memory and you can [decode it in chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/888489/13508) and send it as you go or store it in a file.
- You can replace `serialize()` with an alternative implementation that operates in chunks or switch to another format.